# Ошибка при компиляции Aseprite

Tags: llvm

Пытаюсь самостоятельно скомпилировать программу Aseprite. Дошел до момента где мне нужно вести команду `gn gen out/Release --args="is_official_build=true skia_use_system_expat=false skia_use_system_libjpeg_turbo=false skia_use_system_libpng=false skia_use_system_libwebp=false skia_use_system_zlib=false target_cpu=""x64"" cc=""clang"" cxx=""clang++"" clang_win=""c:\deps\llvm"" win_vc=""G:\Visual Studio\VC"`.
После ввода получаю ошибку:`ERROR Need exactly one build directory to generate.
I expected something more like "gn gen out/foo"
You can also see "gn help gen".`

Answer (score 0):

В конце команды только одна двойная кавычка, похоже, что после `G:\Visual Studio\VC` не хватает `""`